# UV unwrapping with triangulation?

Tags: uv

I cant figure out how this object was unwrapped to keep the UV island square with tris.
[image]

Below is my copy of the object before merging vertices together, I've unwrapped and used follow active quads to square up the island.
[image]

This is what happens to my UVs after merging vertices together.
[image]

Comment: Yes, UV mapping is essentially turning vertex position in 3d space and mapping it to a postion in 2D space. If you project the UV mapwith a certain number of vertices and then delete or merge some of the vertices it is going to lead to this effect. Can I ask why you want to delete these specific vertices though? Is this model for use in a game engine by chance and you just want to save on polycount?

Comment: Yes!, Ive just been looking at game assets trying to replicate them for my own educational purposes. Figuring out what I need to do to get similar results. Some things I just cant figure out how it was done though/

Comment: I would not worry about reducing poly count here. Alot of info out there about acceptable poly count in games is outdated. These days, poly count is not a huge impact on performance (at least within reason). You're saving like 8? vertices with this reduction, when we've got tools like Nanite in UE5 that can handle meshes straight from ZBrush at 60 fps. Make sure you have enough geo to get the shape you want without too much faceting and then if one of the tech artists or devs says your meshes are causing performance issues, go back and reduce polycount.

Comment: With modern graphics pipelines, the things that have the highest capacity to impact performance are things like: draw calls (the CPU telling the GPU to render an object or group of objects), quad-overdraw (GPU taking the time to render 4 pixels when only one pixel has geo that needs to be rendered in it) and alpha overdraw (GPU calculating transparent pixels unnecessarily). With the last two, too LITTLE geometry is actually more likely to cause these issues. Check out [this](https://80.lv/articles/creating-next-gen-grass-in-ue4/) article for more info about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about cylinder projection?

[image]

Comment: Havent used cylinder projection much, very handy & worked like a charm! Thank you